# Adding Two Measurements of height in feets and inches

Tags: java

I have two inputs of float values `5.9f`, `9.11f` which is 5 feet 9 inch and 9 feet 11 inch. I need to add them and display 15 feet 8 inches.

```
public static void addingFeets(float a,float b)
{
    int c = (int)a*12;      
    int d = (int)b*12;      
    float e = Math.round((a%1)*10);     
    float f = Math.round((b%1)*10);     
    float g = (int) ((int)e+f);     
    int h = (int) (c+d+g);    
    System.out.println( h/12+" feet "+h%12+" inches");          
}
```

but I am not able to get the proper output when one of the input contains 11 inches.

Comment: Why would you use a float?

Comment: `a%1` is a code smell

Comment: For a start, 9.11f is not 9 feet, eleven inches, it's 9feet, 1.32 inches. Assuming you're determined to persist with this cock-eyed notation, where you have 11 inches you need to multiply your fractional part by 100, not 10. Really, you should store your feet and inches as accurate decimals where 5'9" is 5.75ft. Then you can add and subtract easily, converting for display and rounding where necessary.

Comment: Are any of the answers working for you?

Comment: yes the one by elliott is woking

Answer (score 2):

5 feet 9 inches cannot be represented as 5.9f, since 1 feet != 10 inches.

The better solution is to do OO modelling on heights - correct code and beautiful code in a jiffy:

```
class Height {
    private int feet;
    private int inches;

    public Height(int feet, int inches) {
        this.feet = feet;
        this.inches = inches;
    }

    public static Height fromInches(int inches) {
        //Convert to feet and inches.
        return new Height(inches / 12, inches % 12);
    }

    public int toInches(){
        return feet * 12 + inches;
    }

    public Height addTo(Height another){
        //1. Convert both the heights to inches
        //2. Do simple addition of inches
        //3. Convert it back to Height using Height.fromInches, and return it
        // or, in other words (behold your eyes):

        return Height.fromInches(this.toInches() + another.toInches());
    }

    //Bonus        
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s'%s\"", feet, inches);
    }
}
```

Now, you could just say:

```
    Height height1 = new Height(5, 9);
    Height height2 = new Height(9, 11);
    System.out.println(height1.addTo(height2));
```

which will nicely print:

```
15'8"
```

Comment: @mikeyaworski Totally agree, but couldn't just resist doing it the right way (which is subjective)

Comment: I said that when all you had was the outline of the class. This still won't do what he wants, but it's at least better.

Comment: @mikeyaworski I thought the idea in SO was not to spoon-feed. In any case, I'll just jump in and fill the addTo() implementation. Hope the anti-spoon-feed camp forgives me here.

Comment: Spoon-feed? Your answer doesn't answer his question **at all**. It doesn't point him in the right direction for what he needs. He doesn't want someone to make a class outline for him, he wants some suggestions on the code he has already started. You don't need to give him copy-and-paste code, but you need to give him something relevant to what he's asking for.

Comment: @mikeyaworski The gist of my answer being '5 feet 9 inches cannot be represented as 5.9f , since 1 feet != 10 inches.' (which was the fundamental and absolutely wrong assumption that that OP made, i.e. even modelling a height as a float). Of course I could have told the OP to model it as a String and split it on the '.' and blah blah. The OO way just made a lot of sense. And I thought all this will help the OP in some way. I didn't get the copy-paste bit: I hope you didn't mean that I just copied the code from somewhere and dumped it in here.

Comment: It's much better now. I agree with an Object oriented approach as well. I also agree that 5.9 shouldn't be 5ft 9in, but I understand why he wants it like that. It's easy to write. The copy-and-paste thing was just I don't expect answers to give answers that the OP can copy and paste and forget about (answers can be purely explanation as well).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
private static int inchesFromString(String in) {
  if (in != null) {
    String[] a = in.split("\\.");
    int feet = (a.length > 0) ? Integer
        .valueOf(a[0]) : 0;
    int inches = (a.length > 1) ? Integer
        .valueOf(a[1]) : 0;
    return (feet * 12) + inches;
  }
  return -1;
}

public static void addingFeets(float a, float b) {
  String one = Float.toString(a);
  String two = Float.toString(b);
  int h = inchesFromString(one) + inchesFromString(two);
  System.out.println(h / 12 + " feet " + h % 12
      + " inches");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
  addingFeets(5.9f, 9.11f);
}
```

Which when I run it, outputs -

```
15 feet 8 inches
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (using a JDK class made to deal with numbers):

```
    float a = 5.9f, b = 9.11f;
    String one = Float.toString(a);

    BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal (one);
    BigDecimal r1 = bd1.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
    BigDecimal r2 = r1.movePointRight(r1.scale());
    int aInches = r2.intValue();
    int aFeet = bd1.intValue ();
    int aTot = (aFeet * 12) + aInches;

    String two = Float.toString(b);
    BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal (two);
    BigDecimal br1 = bd2.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
    BigDecimal br2 = br1.movePointRight(br1.scale());
    int bInches = br2.intValue();

    int bFeet = bd2.intValue ();
    int bTot = (bFeet * 12) + bInches;

    int h = aTot + bTot;
    System.out.println( h/12+" feet "+h%12+" inches");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly: you seem to treat 0.11 as 0 feet 11 inches.

However, then Math.round rounds to the nearest decimal value, so:

```
Math.round((.11%1)*10) = 
Math.round(1.1)=
1
```

Try:

```
e = Math.round( (a%1) * 10 ) + Math.round( ((a*10)%1) * 10 )
```

However this will cause you a problem: 0.1 = 0.10, so is that one inch or ten?  I would suggest that you use 0.01 for 0 feet 1 inch.  Then you have:

```
e = (a%1)*100
```

Answer (score 0):

With Lombok [`@Data`](http://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html) for constructor, getters, setters and `toString`:

```
package com.stackoverflow.so20779885;

import lombok.Data;

public class App {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final FootInch fi1 = new FootInch(5, 9);
        final FootInch fi2 = new FootInch(9, 11);

        System.out.println(fi1.add(fi2)); // App.FootInch(feet=15, inches=8)
    }

    @Data
    public static class FootInch {

        private final int feet;
        private final int inches;

        public FootInch add(/* @Nonnull */final FootInch fi2)
        {
            // first we sum directly
            int newFeet = this.feet + fi2.getFeet();
            int newInches = this.inches + fi2.getInches();
            // then we "transfert" every 12 inches to 1 foot:
            newFeet += newInches / 12;
            newInches = newInches % 12;
            // return a new FootInch for the result
            return new FootInch(newFeet, newInches);
        }
    }
}
```

[demo here](http://ideone.com/iDtJ4X).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you consider 5.9 feet, it isn't actually 5 feet 9 inches. Instead it is 5 feet, 10.8 inches. This is because:

> 1 ft = 12 inches
>
> 5.9 ft = 70.8 inches
>
> 70.8 inches = 5 ft 7.5 inches

So, I think you *shouldn't* use float to represent your values as it wouldn't be very accurate.

I think you should try one of the following:

1. Use a String to represent the lengths. Then implement a suitable extraction algorithm.
2. Use two different variables to store feet and inches.

After you get your values correctly, convert both to inches, add, and then again separate the two parts.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating an class for this, but this sloppy code will work as well:

```
float a = 5.9f;
float b = 9.11f;

double f1 = Math.floor(a); // feet of a
double f2 = Math.floor(b); // feet of b

double feet = f1 + f2; // combined feet

int in1 = 0, in2 = 0; // inches of a and b

String s1 = String.valueOf(a), s2 = String.valueOf(b); // String values of a and b

if (s1.contains(".")) // if a contains a radix point
{
    // inches of a is number after radix point
    in1 = Integer.parseInt(s1.substring(s1.indexOf(".") + 1));
}

if (s2.contains(".")) // if b contains a radix point
{
    // inches of b is number after radix point
    in2 = Integer.parseInt(s2.substring(s2.indexOf(".") + 1));
}

int in = in1 + in2; // combined extra inches

feet += in / 12; // add a foot for every 12 extra inches

// take all of the factors of 12 out of the total extra inches (in % 12)
System.out.print((int)feet + " feet " + in % 12 + " inches");
```

This generates output:

```
15 feet 8 inches
```